# How to load one activity from its previous activity, by passing pending Intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent, android-progressbar

I am a beginer,sory may be this is a foolish question,but i don't know how to solve this,.
I have two activities in my app, Activity first and Second, the first activity will load an image from gallery or Camera and displaying it in an imageview on the second activity.In the second activity users can upload the picture to a server by clicking upload button,a notification progress dialogue will shown while the upload is in progress.Users can click any time on the notification progress bar to cancel the upload.When user click on the notification progress a pending intent is passesd like this.

```
 public void ProgressBarNotification() {
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ImageUploadActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload")
                        .setContentText("Upload in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ImageUploadActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ImageUploadActivity.this, 0, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

}
```

And in the onNewIntenet method will load the second activity(ImageUploadActivity) and its method initiatepopupwindow(),and the second activity will be loaded ,even if the app is completely minimized.All these are working fine.

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
     new Intent(this, ImageUploadActivity.class);
    initiatePopupWindow();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Upload ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

My problem is when I am on the first activity( MainActivity) and when i click on the notiification progress bar ,the app will crash and it shows Null Pointer Exception.I know that the problem is that the second activity is killed and so the pending intent is not passing to invoke second activity and its method.But
What i need is ,i want to load the second activity whenever user clicks on the notification progress,  how can i Solve this problem ,Can anybody help??

Logcat

```
07-03 11:06:20.595  31761-31761/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jbn.user.imagegallerydemo/com.jbn.user.imagegallerydemo.ImageUploadActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jbn.user.imagegallerydemo.ImageUploadActivity.onCreate(ImageUploadActivity.java:117)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
           android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

Comment: can't understand your problem

Comment: problem is when i click the back button the app will go to first activity,then that time if i click the notification progress bar the app will crash

Comment: What i need is ,i want to load the second activity whenever user clicks on the notification progress

Comment: i will suggest you to use helper class with static variable context, activity keep updating those variable with your active class... and then use all those in your Notification Intent .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the

```
Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION
```

with the

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

According to docs

> This Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already
>   exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this
>   new Intent.

Comment: But  app still crashes

Comment: Please post you logcat, so that we can help you better

Comment: Its just a NullPointerException, i guess you are calling the 'getIntent().getExtras()' for getting the data from the first activity.